# I can spread like a disease... Riddle

Tags: riddle

> I can spread like a disease,
>
> Only I can't kill,
>
> Unless it's in a phrase.
>
> I can never displease,
>
> Unless you've got skill.
>
> But, I can still infect for many days

What am I?

Hint 1: Might give it all away:

> If you add a letter to me, then I suddenly become more ghastly.

Hint 2: In case you need another:

> No one can control me and they love it. Even psychopaths

Comment: I'm guessing puberty XD I'm just kidding. Welcome to PSE! Please take the tour!

Answer (score 13):

You would probably be

> Laughter

I can spread like a disease,

> Laughter is contagious!

Only I can't kill,

> Laughter can't kill

Unless it's in a phrase.

> **Deadly/Killer** laughter is a common phrase, not that it kills though ....

I can never displease,

> Laughter usually doesn't displease

Unless you've got skill.

> 

But, I can still infect for many days

> Laughter is infectious

If you add a letter to me, then I suddenly become more ghastly.

> **S** + laughter = Slaughter, which is horrific

No one can control me and they love it. Even psychopaths

> Laughter is normally well received. Psychopaths/maniacs usually cackle with laughter

Comment: The phrase is probably rot13(qvrq ynhtuvat)

Comment: i have never heard that phrase.

Comment: I'm thinking "I can never displease, Unless you've got skill" refers to rot13(gvpxyr gbeghr)

Comment: Monty Python would not be happy about this solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVQKRqJbOTo

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A host?

I can spread like a disease,

> Diseases spread through hosts

Only I can't kill,

> Hosts can’t kill but the viruses do

Unless it's in a phrase.

> 

I can never displease,

> Hosts aim to please at social gatherings

Unless you've got skill.

> 

But, I can still infect for many days

> Viruses in hosts infect for many days

Hint:

> If you add a letter to me, then I suddenly become more ghastly. -> G + HOST = GHOST

Comment: I think the skill hint has to do with rot13(tnzr fubj ubfg), can't figure out the phrase one though.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Silence

I can spread like a disease,

> Silence can be contagious

Only I can't kill,

> Silence usually does not kill

Unless it's in a phrase.

> A phrase like "Silence can be killer"

I can never displease,

> Silence usually does not displease

Unless you've got skill.

> Silence could potentially be displeasing, like passive aggressive

But, I can still infect for many days

> People might stop talking for many days

Hint 1

> Silenced (silence + d) could mean murdered

Hint 2

> If a person decides to be silent no one can make him talk

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Words

I can spread like a disease,

> Words can be contagious (gossip)

Only I can't kill,

> Words don't usually kill

Unless it's in a phrase.

> Words can make people suicide

I can never displease,

> Words usually does not displease

Unless you've got skill.

> If you are good with words, you can displease

But, I can still infect for many days

> Words can be top gossip

Comment: Ooh the hints could be (rot13) f+jbeqf = fjbeqf naq lbh pna'g pbageby jbeqf!